# Gerar um array de múltiplas variáveis em python

Tags: python, array, pandas, csv, numpy

Olá! Estou tentando gerar uma função que lê dados importados de um arquivo "csv" e o os converta para um array. 
Os dados de uma coluna são do tipo integer, e da outra coluna são uma intercalação de strings e integer, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que escrevi até agora foi:
"

```
def sundata(arquivo):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s_data = pd.read_csv(arquivo, delimiter = ';')
par_dat = []


for i,j in zip( par_dat['Az'] , par_dat['data'] ):

    par_data = np.append(par_dat,[[i],[j]])


    par_dat= np.reshape(par_dat,(len(data['Az']),2))

return par_dat
```

"
O que recebo é o erro seguinte: "List indices must be integers or slices, not strings". Se alguém puder ajudar serei muito grato :)

Comment: qual o motivo pra você fazer isso? o pandas não  seria suficiente para te ajudar a fazer qualquer operação com esses dados? existe alguma restrição?

Comment: Eu preciso utilizar uma função dentro de uma biblioteca chamada Pymag. Na função, eu entro com uma série de dados e ela retorna um valor inteiro. Se eu tivesse poucos dados eu poderia fazer uma lista ou inserir um a um. Mas acontece que tenho mais de 1000 dados e fazer cada um deles é inviável. Então estou tentando criar uma forma de inseri-los todos de uma vez na função pra depois criar um txt da resposta de cada dado.Então estou tentando importar o dado do csv e transformálo em um array pra chamá-lo na função.O problema é que um dos dados que o algoritimo pede é da forma da coluna "data"...

Comment: precisa preserva o nome das colunas?

Comment: Não, não é preciso!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No próprio pandas você tem um método chamado `values` que converte o dataframe em um `array`.

```
def sundata(arquivo):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    s_data = pd.read_csv(arquivo, delimiter = ';')
    par_dat = s_data.values

    return par_dat
```

Outra opção seria utilizar outro método do pandas o `to_numpy`, que converte o dataframe já em um `numpy.array`

```
def sundata(arquivo):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    s_data = pd.read_csv(arquivo, delimiter = ';')
    par_dat = s_data.to_numpy()

    return par_dat
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!